# How to fix requireShorthandArrowFunctions

Tags: node.js, jscs

How to fix this requireShorthandArrowFunctions arrow function so that it is compliant with JSCS?

```
const doSomething = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        resolve('success');

    });
};
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSCS, but what it looks like it wants is something like `return new Promise(resolve => resolve('success'); );`

Comment: I tried that but still show error

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I just had the same issue. I figured out it's because your `doSomething` function does only one thing - it returns a promise. So, technically you shouldn't use a `return` statement and curly braces:

```
const doSomething = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("success");
});
```